# How to time shift x-axis in mathematica simulation?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-value, webmathematica

I have a simulation from a system of equations that runs from 0 to 50

```
Normal = 
  NDSolve[{A /. Parameter, A[0] == .1}, {A[t]}, {t, 0, 50}];
```

That produces:

[image]

Now I want the same exact graph but to be shifted to t= 10 i.e. the simulation should start at t = 10. I still want the graph to go from 0 to 50. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's about to shift the scale of plot? `FrameTicks->{Table[{(i-1)*10,(i-1)*10-10},{i,1,6}],Automatic}]`

Comment: First determine what part is Line in your plot: `Position[plot,Line]`, say it is `{{1,1,1,3,1,2,0}}`. Then you may select points to keep in plot: `plot[[1,1,1,3,1,2,1]]=Select[plot[[1,1,1,3,1,2,1]],#[[1]]>=10&]`, then repeat plot. Not elegant, but works.

Comment: Another variant: `plot/.Line[{__}]:>(Cases[plot,Line[{x__}]:>x,\[Infinity]]//Select[#[[1]]>=10&])`